# Why Yield is not working with request module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

I have a scenario, where I have got an array of URL's that needs to be evaluated synchronously using request npm module. In details, Array will be forEach and it should bring data for current url and after then only move to pick next url. I am using yield generators. But It's not working. Please help guys!

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"), {multiArgs: true});
Promise.promisifyAll(request, {multiArgs: true})
var url_arr = ["https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=AIzaSyDe3MyoHI6aSbYKdHOXloz9QepAMfes9XE", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=AIzaSyDe3MyoHI6aSbYKdHOXloz9QepAMfes9XE"];


function* fetch(obj) {
  console.log("2")
  var myobj = yield request.getAsync(obj).promise();
  console.log("3", myobj)
  return myobj;
}

url_arr.forEach(function (obj){
  console.log("1", obj)
  var output = fetch(obj);
  console.log("4, ", output);
});
```

In above snippet, Only **1** && **4** are printed in console. Two and three are never evaluated I think.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluated"? Why do you `return` from within generator function?

Comment: Note that the code at Question appears to mix asynchronous code with synchronous code using `.forEach()`. Is the expected result the response from an asynchronous request to be logged within `.forEach()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `return` statement from generator function, which suspends the generator, call `.next()` to get the `value` of the `yield`ed object

```js
function* _fetch(obj) {
  var myobj = yield obj;
}

[1,2,3].forEach(function (obj) {
  var {value:output} = _fetch(obj).next();
  console.log("output:", output);
});
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked!!!! Now I want to ask can we automate the process and remove .next()?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve you can use `yield` expression and `for..of` loop `function* _fetch(obj) {
  var myobj = yield* obj;
}; for (let prop of _fetch([1,2,3])) {
  console.log(prop)
}`